# ArgumentError ao chamar função

Tags: ruby

Estou tentando executar esse meu código abaixo:

```
class ProdutItem

  attr_reader :price_unit, :x_item, :price_promo

  def initialize(price_unit: , x_item: 1, price_promo: price_unit)
    @price_unit = price_unit
    @x_item = x_item
    @price_promo = price_promo
  end

  def price_qtde(units)
    units_promo = units / @x_item
    units_eo = units % @x_item
    @price_promo * units_promo + @price_unit * units_eo
  end

end

rules = ProdutItem.new(price_unit: 50, x_item: 3, price_promo: 130)
puts rules.price_qtde
```

Porem está aparecendo esse erro abaixo:

> ```
> Checkout.rb:11:in `price_qtde': wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1) (ArgumentError)
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A função `price_qtde` recebe um parâmetro (`units`), mas ao chamar essa função na última linha do seu código, não está informando argumento algum.

Se o valor de `units` devesse ser `2`, então faça:

```
puts rules.price_qtde 2
```

ou

```
puts rules.price_qtde(2)
```